# Question Template for better question structures

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, asking-questions

We are often faced with questions that are incomplete or unclear. There are alot of prerequisites for solving those issues. Should we not include a simple template so that individuals who ask questions can make sure they include all the important informations.

I would request that these short simple text should be designed to be included in the question entry text box as a visual checklist as to improve the chances of questions and answers being more accurate.

Eg Template.

> ** *Attention Delete the template text as you fill in your questions. The template is only meant to act as a checklist.*
>
> 1.System - OSX / Windows / Linux ... version
> 2.Blender version
>
> 3.Describe the problem.
> 4.Describe the solutions you have already tried
> and did not work.
> 5.Describe of the purpose and goal of the question.
>
> -- Add images or gifs to give further example to the problem.
> -- Add a simplified blend file that produces the problem.
> -- Add code snippets if the question requires.
> -- Format your questions so that it's easy to read if it's long.

Comment: I like this idea, it's similar to how bug reports should be structured and this would actually help a lot. I'm not sure how practical or feasible however, I'm sure this has been suggested before. I'd check meta.se to see and I'll poke around.

Comment: My concern with a template like this is that some of the info is not necessary for every question. OS and blender version are seldom the issue.

Comment: Your concern is valid, however it works as a checklist for the person asking the question. In any case the template will be deleted after the OP have filled up the text box with his question. Maybe we could add a line of text suggesting to OP that it's a checklist and remove those text as you fill in the answer. I have updated the example Template.

Comment: @cegaton Every point need not be ticked but rather could be used as a guide, maybe some bolded that **must** be in the body such as blender version.